# Possible implications (if any) of the MIT License change in SO on the SQA front

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

Most of you would have seen by now that [Stack Overflow is moving to a new license as of Feb 1,2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange?cb=1).

I went through all the comments, and as a QA/Testing person, I am not sure what (if there are) any possible implications on the code/knowledge sharing that we do have here.

Are there going to be any significant changes in terms of how we share code- for Open source or licensed softwares?